# iOS 7 Storyboard Autolayout uitableviewcontroller tableviewheader parallax

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, parallax

I've got trapped in some weird problem.

I want to use `Autolayout` with `UITableViewController` along with `tableHeaderView` to stick to 
TOP and stretch it (the table header ) just like parallax effect found in other apps.

I know there are other solutions on the github but i am not able to find anything to this specific issue.

What I have done is :

1. Create Single View App new project (Used Version 5.1.1 (5B1008))
2. replaced default view controller scene with `uitableviewcontroller`
3. Made the table view to have 2 or 3 static cells
4. Added a `UIView` (with `UIImage` view in left align vertical center constrains) as a table header view
5. added the following code to `viewcontroller.m` (inherited from `UITableviewController`)

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    headerOriginalFrame = self.myHeaderView.frame;
}


-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat offsetY = -(scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top);
    offsetY = MAX( 0.0, offsetY );
    CGRect rect = headerOriginalFrame;
    rect.origin.y = -offsetY;
    rect.size.height = headerOriginalFrame.size.height + offsetY;
    self.myHeaderView.frame = rect;
}
```

This does creates a parallax effect along with header view constraints.

But the problem is that the origin point of the header view doesn't stick to tableview origin.

It does come down as we pull the downward side.

Also not able to see any way to add constraints to the `UITableViewController`.

I want to do it all in the `UITableViewController` without adding other library.

I hope there is some way to stick header to the top and get this job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your frame of content view (I guess imageView ) not header view itself.

1. create `IBOutlet* myHeaderContentView` and connect your content what you wanna effect in headerView.
2. replace all `myHeaderView` with `myHeaderContentView` in above code.
3. don't forget this.  `self.myHeaderView.clipsToBounds = NO;`

done. I tested it.

Comment: I prefer use UIViewController with UITableView not UITableViewController. With UITableViewController, It is difficult to customize.

Comment: +1 for the answer. But have also problem with the content view to set in the center of the header view.

Comment: Can you show me the constraint details to keep the image centered in the content view

Comment: Because you change a frame of content view not NSLayoutConstraint, you need to change a frame of image view to keep centered in content view. You already change a frame of content view using scroll offset, I know you also can do that.